# Apply conditional formating on Table Visualization - Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, conditional-formatting

Trying to apply conditional formatting on Table Visualization in Power BI I received a warning to check the logic of my rule. The logic I want to apply is simple, if the value is 0, set a tick else set a cross.

Find below the warning received:

[image].

**Update based on @davidebacci answer:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How can the number be both greater than zero **and** less than zero at the same time? You have contradictory logic in your branch.

Try this:

Add a third rule. In your second existing rule, type 9e9 in the fifth box.
In your third rule, type > -9e9 < 0. You can add a cross icon for this branch too.

Comment: have a look on the updated quetions. Do you angry with the new logic?

Comment: Looks correct to me - does it work? When you tab out of the values that say 9e9, they should convert to a very large number. If not, input a large number yourself.